# How to forward hostname based request to a specific docker container

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, hostname, docker

I'm trying to use hostname based connecting to a docker container. i.e: I connect my browser to web01.docker.example.org (assuming a wildcard DNS record on *.docker.example.org pointing to my docker box). How do I enable docker to forward this request to my nginx docker for instance?

This idea is inspired by apache's VirtualNameHost model, which does this, except to a VirtualHost rather then a running container.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to dispatch connections to a different Docker container based on the hostname that was used to access it, using a single public IP address ?

That is not possible in general; docker operates with TCP or UDP conversations, and their endpoints are IP addresses, not hostnames.

If you want to do this with HTTP, you can setup a reverse proxy container, that will relay the HTTP request to the correct machine. Otherwise, you will have to use one distinct IP address per container.